# How do I change my registered address with the FCC?

Tags: united-states, license, fcc

I just moved, and I want to change my registered address with my call-sign.

- Is there a form or something somewhere that I can fill out?
- Do I have to mail it, or can I turn it in to the FCC or something electronically?
- Does it cost anything?
- What will happen if I fail to get my address updated for a while?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the link that describes how to update your FCC information.

http://wireless.fcc.gov/services/index.htm?id=amateur&job=cft&page=cft_change_address

I do mine on the website and I have not been charged for it.  Within a few weeks a new copy of your license with the new address will arrive in the mail.

As for not updating in a timely manner, if you do something that requires the FCC to contact you and they are unable to is when it's time to worry.  I believe fines start around $2700 for that but I may be wrong.

Comment: "Revocation of your station license or suspension of your operator license may result when correspondence from the FCC is returned as undeliverable because you failed to provide the correct mailing address."

Comment: These days FCC will email you before they send you snail mail, assuming you've registered both.